# How do I use API's with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make a twitterbot that posts a few news headlines every hour. I have the code to post to twitter, and it works. However, I'm not sure how to use API's in NodeJS as I am fairly new to javacript. If someone can help use the newsapi.org api, that would be great.

I don't know much about API's and get requests, so keep that in mind when answering.

Comment: As a start probably look up some nodeJS libraries that are related to twitter. Read up their examples and see how you could utilize it. E.g. of 1 such library, which I googled and think could be helpful to you is https://github.com/ttezel/twit

Comment: Using pure node.js you can create requests using http.requests: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Comment: @SamuelToh Yeah, I'm using the twitter module already.

Comment: @Hkessel1 Do you want to expose those modules so you can access through a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you mean by "API"; there are several different things that could fall under that umbrella.

There are public APIs, like [this one](http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json), which can be accessed from anywhere by any client/language/platform that can make a GET request, and there are restricted APIs, like the News API you mention, that require you to register for an API key and limit or monitor your usage based on that unique identifier.

In addition, since you're using Node.js, there are also libraries and APIs wrapped as packages or "modules" that you can find on [npm](http://npmjs.com) (which comes bundled with Node) and import into your code.

The easiest way to make a GET request to the News API is using one such module, [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

First, install the package:

```
npm install request -g
```

Then, simply import it into your code and make the request to the News API using your key from the site:

```js
const request = require("request");
request("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey={API_KEY}", function(err, res, body) {
    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200) { // Successful response
        console.log(body); // Displays the response from the API
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, works amazingly! I have a question, since it prints the body in html form, how can I tweet this? Here's my current code:
http://pastebin.com/K7YmKcDV


As you can see, for now it prints "test", how can I get it to print what it console.log'd? Should I turn the code you provided into a function and then call it where "test." is?

Comment: @Hkessel1 I would actually turn the tweeting into a function instead, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/r65y8goz/.

Comment: It works, thanks so much. Next I'm going to look at automating it. What if I were to turn the tweet function into another function and then use setInterval(function, delay) to execute it every x seconds?

Comment: *Edited my response again

Comment: @Hkessel1 That could work, but you'll have to check to make sure you haven't posted that article already.

Comment: Oh yeah, hmm. 
What about this? http://pastebin.com/43GhbKaJ I'm unsure why it didn't work, is it because I didn't specify a function permiiter?

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) works like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vu8c1p0m/.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry you're practically spoonfeeding me!

Comment: @Hkessel1 No, I'm happy to help! Everyone's new at this at some point.

Comment: Just to clarify, setInterval makes it repeat every five seconds, right?

Comment: The second parameter is the interval in milliseconds, so if you pass in 5000, it'll repeat every 5000 milliseconds (i.e. 5 seconds).

Comment: (I'd love to move this to a chat room but I need more rep) I've improved by code, here's the new version: http://pastebin.com/d0M58Xbx The problem is that my bot only uses the first article from my source (in this case google-news). How can I get it to use the other articles listed in the get request too? Register for newsapi.org (it's free) and click the get request in your browser and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a way to make a single request with all of the sources, but you could query [this endpoint](https://newsapi.org/v1/sources) in a similar way and loop through the sources.

Comment: The problem isn't with the source (it delivers a lot of news) it's that my code isn't using all the articles provided by the source, only the first one.

Comment: Ah, I see – notice how in the code I posted, the variable is called `firstArticle`? That's because it only pulls the first article from the source; the API returns an array of articles, and I just used the first one for the example by taking `body.articles[0]`. If you want to use all of them, you'll have to loop through the `body.articles` array.

Answer (score 0):

just in case if your question is about how to trigger an api using node js and to get the data from it ! I used the code given below for the same :-

```
    var soap=require('soap');               
 var url = "your_url?wsdl";
    var args1 = { "key" : "value"  };

    soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
        client.Servicename.portname.functionname (args1, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Get_Information_All ");
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

U will get the servicename,port name,function name by opening the wsdl directory of that particular api .